# MacOs Catalina and Kerberos Config

Tags: macos, kerberos, macos-catalina, azure-data-studio

I am trying to access on prem Sql Server via Azure Data Studio. However I am hitting with some errors in Kerberos.

Below are the series of errors that getting thrown.

1. When trying to connect Sql Server via Azure Data Studio , the below error is thrown.
   **"Connection failed due to Kerberos" and it asks me to run "kinit"**
2. When running the "kinit" the below error is thrown.
   **"kinit: krb5_get_init_creds: unable to reach any KDC in realm LOCAL, tried 0 KDCs"**

Googling the above error suggested me to modify the **/etc/krb5.conf** . However, I was not able locate this file in my Mac. I am running MacOs Catalina.

Does anyone know where this file is located?

-Alan-

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up your Kerberos Key Distribution Centre (KDC) on your Mac:

```
sudo vi /etc/krb5.conf

[libdefaults]
  default_realm = DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM
 
[realms]
DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM = {
   kdc = dc-33.domain.company.com
}
```

Make sure you use all caps when replacing the top `DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM` and don't forget to replace the bottom one as well.

Comment: This file does not exist under '/etc' in my macOS (I only see 'krb5.keytab'). Do I need to create it, or does it automatically get created after running kinit?